# Ionic build android error Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com...'

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I've searched for hours and none of them can solve my issue. I've checked `ionic info` command and this was the result

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.1
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

The command I run `ionic cordova build --debug android` and it fails with this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3-2.
  >    Required by:
  >        project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.0
  >        project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.0.0
  >        project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.0.0
  >        project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.0.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.0.0
  >        project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.0.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.0.0 > com.android.tools:repository:26.0.0
  >        project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.0.0
  >   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3-2.
  >   Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.1.3-2/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.3-2.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.1.3-2/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.3-2.pom'.
  >   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:80 [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156] failed: Connection timed out: connect
  >   Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:5.1.
  >    Required by:
  >        project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.0
  >        project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.0.0
  >        project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.0.0
  >   Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:5.1.
  >   Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.1/asm-5.1.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.1/asm-5.1.pom'.
  >   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:80 [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156] failed: Connection timed out: connect
  >   Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:5.1.
  >    Required by:
  >        project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.0
  >        project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.0.0
  >   Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:5.1.
  >   Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.1/asm-analysis-5.1.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.1/asm-analysis-5.1.pom'.
  >   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:80 [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156] failed: Connection timed out: connect

There is no proxy that we are using. I don't know what I missed at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone having the same issue, I've installed VPN on my machine and now able to download the files needed and everything works.